# Spring Security when to use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-security

can someone explain me when to use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and when UserDetailsService. I just started learning spring security, noticed that extending both interfaces you can create security implementation. But which one I should use if I want to create security for web project connection from angular based site and user data saved in Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The components you are talking about have very different responsibilities and therefore the question *do I use one or the other?* does not really make sense. Take a look at the JavaDocs of those components to learn the difference.

#### [`UserDetailsService`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html)

> Core interface which loads user-specific data. It is used throughout the framework as a user DAO and is the strategy
>   used by the DaoAuthenticationProvider. The interface requires only one read-only method, which simplifies
>   support for new data-access strategies.

#### [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html)

> Provides a convenient base class for creating a WebSecurityConfigurer instance. The implementation allows customization by overriding methods.

---

For example you could have security configuration class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and uses custom  `UserDetailsService` to load user information like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder());
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The core components of Spring Security and their responsibilities are also nicely described in the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#overall-architecture).

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Yea my bad, didn't catch in the beginning.

Comment: @Edgar No problem. I added link to my answer pointing to the reference guide, namely the *Internal architecture* section. All of the core components are described there. I recommend to take a look at it :)